# Accessing google docs via a program in php and not in a browser

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to access, view, modify Google docs but via a program written in php. 
I would prefer to use API protocol as it can be used by any language.

But apparently the API requires me to be signed in in a browser. Now if I want to make a server side script that apparently wont be running in a browser, how can I do that?

I didnt found any username/password/auth giving thing that returns me some token and the API can use that token.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell

google would not know who sent the second request if it does not has the access token or some way to prove that it logged in a minut a go. in my case: the program (lets say php server)

I guess this would not help https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests for https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell as the later has no access token option.

Comment: You can use CURL: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL I am sure, the newer version has documentation also.

Comment: so theres no other proper way?

Comment: What do you mean, other proper way? You can manipulate Curl from php too. http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: "proper way" means some support by Google API that accepts credentials and gives some token. Like in Google calendar apps.

Comment: maybe this? https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib i do not really know. i stop commenting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all but I found something working exactly as required.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.html

Answer (score 0):

You should authenticate your clients with OAuth2 and then store the tokens in db: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

Also there's a client library available from Google: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

Edit: As you said it's about the spreadsheet API I'm linkin directly to the spreadsheet API authentication documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20 seems they support OAuth2 too.

Comment: Thanks NiklasN but I guessed that the said spreadsheet Google API does not has a parameter for a token nor a username/password. That was the problem I faced.

Comment: I edited the answer with a link to the spreadsheet authorization documentation.

Comment: Thanks but the link is supporting .net and Java only. no API unless the following link which is I _think_ not fully programatic: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps